# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' - Python

Tags: python, syntax

```
# from lxml import etree; 
import module2dbk; 
print module2dbk.xsl_transform(etree.parse('test-ccap/col10614/index.cnxml'), []);

Error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the script gets executed by bash, not python. Try adding `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of the file.

Comment: why is your first line commented out ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you typing this at the unix command prompt? You should be doing this inside the python environment, ie. type `python` at the prompt and work from there.

Also, no `;` needed at the end of the line in Python

Comment: @Erri no need to feel stupid, we've all been there :)

Answer (score 71):

add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script, or call your script using `python myscript.py`

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. I've made this mistake more than a few times.

Answer (score 15):

add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or but i will prefer to use the above one.

`#!/usr/bin/python`

In case you have installed python 2 and python 3 and python 2 is default you can run python 3 by using these command

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

at top of the file

or run this way

```
python code.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I had exactly the same problem. I had tried everything and nothing really worked. My program was running perfectly on Windows command prompt, and on my iPhone Python app interpreter, but not on my Macbook's terminal, where I always got the following error whenever I tried to run the program:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Finally the comment above from the user *tripleee* helped me come up with a solution; although his solution of adding `!/usr/bin/python` at the very start of my code didn't do it for me it helped me understand as he wrote that:

> The error message indicates that the script gets executed by bash, not python.

Then I noticed that my code(extra).py contained '(' apostrophes, I renamed to my codeextra.py and that was it, problem solved. :)